# Need help Identifying font from this logo

Tags: fonts

Any help identifying this font would be great. I need to redo this logo and the guy doesn't know what font was used. I've cut it out and made it that way but the edges aren't smooth and look jagged.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it - pay particular attention to what is in scope. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already tried. We have specific requirements for Font ID questions [https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083] please review these and revise your question to meet those requirements - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's simply **URW Impact**. I believe it's installed an many operating systems by default.

In addition to the adding the skew (there's no italic or oblique face which I'm aware of), the `r` appears to be altered slightly.

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/impact

[image]